Using Jinja2 Template to Iterate Over SQL Column Sets to Create DataFrames
I am attempting to use a Jinja template in a for loop to execute a SQL query which groups by different column sets and months. The loop is meant to append each new month of data to the dataframe that's been created for the given column set, then save the final dataframe with a name designated in the column_set_names set.
My current code is looping through all 3 of my column set names and the 3 column sets I designated resulting in 9 queries, none of which are saved as I expect them to be. I believe there are two issues, I need to limit the iteration through the set names so each is only produced once, and I need to figure out how to assign the correct df_name to each of the resulting dataframes. For instance my desired output for the first column set would be
location_df = 'town', 'county', 'state', 'nbr_rows', 'purchases', 'revenue', 'month'
Please let me know if I can provide any detail on what I'm trying to do.
sql_query_template = """
SELECT
    {{ group_by_columns | join(', ') }},
    COUNT(*) AS nbr_rows,
    SUM(purchases) AS purchases
    SUM(revenue) AS revenue
FROM
    purchase_hist
WHERE
    month = '{{ month }}'
GROUP BY
    {{ group_by_columns | join(', ') }}
"""


column_set_names = ['location', 'age_gender', 'product_desc']
group_by_column_sets = [['town', 'county', 'state'], ['age', 'gender'], ['prod_name', 'prod_type', 'prod_origin'],]
month_param = ['202407']

for set_name in column_set_names:
    df_name = f'{set_name}_df'
    
    for group_by_columns in group_by_column_sets:
        template = Template(sql_query_template)
        combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

        for month_param in months_param:
            rendered_query = template.render(group_by_columns=group_by_columns, month=month_param)

            df_name = pd.read_sql(rendered_query, cnxn)

            df_name['month'] = month_param

            df_name = pd.concat([combined_df, df_name], ignore_index=True)

